# How to load a png image as an array in Julia?

Tags: image, julia

How can I load a png as an array using Julia? I have a 256X256 image and I would like to load it as a 256X256 float array.

I tried using Images

```
using Images

img = load("pic.png")
```

however this merely loads and plots the image and I am not able to extract pixel values.

Additionally, I have tried

```
img = read("pic.png")
```

but this loads all the values into a vector. In theory I can reshape the vector to make it 256X256, but I was hoping for something that could work without me having to know the shape of the image ahead of time.

Lastly, if I load PyPlot I can load the image exactly how I want

```
import PyPlot as plt

img = plt.imread("pic.png")
```

however I would ideally like to be able to load the image with without invoking PyCall and.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use FileIO. FileIO will choose appropiate parser (could be ImageMagick but for png it will be raher PNGFiles.jl instead). This provides you a common central interface for accessing images.

Note that this approach is also recommended on the [ImageMagick.jl GitHub page](https://github.com/JuliaIO/ImageMagick.jl)

```
julia> using FileIO

julia> img = FileIO.load("c:\\temp\\fig.png")
288×432 Array{RGBA{N0f8},2} with eltype ColorTypes.RGBA{FixedPointNumbers.N0f8}:
 RGBA{N0f8}(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0)  …  RGBA{N0f8}(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0)
 RGBA{N0f8}(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0)     RGBA{N0f8}(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0)
 ⋮                            ⋱
 RGBA{N0f8}(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0)  …  RGBA{N0f8}(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0)
 RGBA{N0f8}(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0)     RGBA{N0f8}(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0)
```

If you want this as a 3 dimensional `Array` you need to be `using Images` and try `channelview`:

```
julia> imgarr = channelview(img)
4×288×432 reinterpret(reshape, N0f8, ::Array{RGBA{N0f8},2}) with eltype N0f8:
[:, :, 1] =
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  …  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0     1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
...
```

If you want a different order of dimensions this can be further combined with `permutedims(imgarr, [2,3,1])`

Comment: This is great! How can this be converted into an array? In this case because it is RGB, I would expect it to be a NXNX3 array.

Comment: there you go - answer edited