# Most efficient way to read 4000 Imgs and gather them in shape of a Matrix

Tags: julia

Using Julia, I want to read 4000 images distributed equally in ten directories from the [TinyMNIST dataset](https://github.com/AgaMiko/tiny-mnist-challenge/blob/master/data/TinyMNIST.zip) and gather their Float value in a `Matrix{Float64}`. I tried the following code:

```
using FileIO, Images, BenchmarkTools

const paths::Vector{String} = readdir(
    raw"<PATH>\TinyMNIST\train"; join=true
)

function ret4000(paths::Vector{String})::Matrix{Float64}
    reduce(hcat, _ret400.(paths))
end

function _ret400(path::String)::Matrix{Float64}
    # `set1` is a Vector of 400 images' path
    set1::Vector{String} = readdir(path; join=true);
    # `b` is a Vector of 400 matrixes of size 28x28
    b::Vector{Matrix{Float64}} = [Float64.(x) for x=FileIO.load.(set1)]
    # `c` is a Vector that contains 400 matrix of size 784x1
    c::Vector{Matrix{Float64}} = [reshape(x, :, 1) for x=b]
    # horizontal concatenation of all 400 matrixes of size 784x1 to form a matrix of size 784x400
    reduce(hcat, c)
end
```

And benchmarking gives me the following:

```
julia> @benchmark ret4000($paths)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 1 sample with 1 evaluation.
 Single result which took 5.187 s (0.25% GC) to evaluate,
 with a memory estimate of 148.41 MiB, over 1222457 allocations.

julia> typeof(ret4000(paths))
Matrix{Float64} (alias for Array{Float64, 2})

julia> size(ret4000(paths))
(784, 4000)
```

Is there any way to make this process faster? I tried utilizing the TensorCast.jl package to make the `reduce(hcat, c)` faster, but it didn't significantly improve.

Comment: why not using `channelview` as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74482038/how-to-load-a-png-image-as-an-array-in-julia

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel, Ah, yes, you're right. But it doesn't make the performance better. In my case, it makes it worse.

Comment: I do not know your exact use case scenario but I would expect 95% of time to be png processing and maybe 5% some copying data in memory (if any). So if more performance is needed I would rather go towards @distributed etc. rather than optimize beyond what `channelview` has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past, knowing beforehand the equal sizes of my images as you appearently also do, is to use a color view of a preallocated `mmap`ed array of the appropriate size, something like

```
images = colorview(
    RGBA,
    mmap(Array{Float64, 4}, IMGS, 4, IMGS * IMG_HEIGHT, IMGS * IMG_WIDTH)
)
```

(4 is the number of channels in RGBA).  You can of course drop the `mmap` if your data fits in memory well (it was necessary in my use case).

Then you can access each individual image as

```
images[n, :, :, :] .= load(paths[n])
```

Unfortuantely, there is no in-place variant of `load`, but that is probably because we cannot in general know the size of an image beforehand.  Your format of vectors of matrices can be recovered through `eachslice` and similar functions (or just views).

In addition, as Premyslaw noted, the limit is probably codec computation, not copying, but as the memory access of each image is independent, the task is easily parallelizable.  This works easily with a `@threads` loop; processes might need more bookkeeping if `mmap` is involved (at least you probably can't use `MAP_ANONYMOUS` anymore).